# How can I create and edit Microsoft Office documents in Android

Tags: ms-office

I'm looking for a way to create and/or edit Microsoft Office compatible documents (.doc/.docx, .xls/.xlsx, .ppt/.pptx...) on my Android device.  Are there any free solution that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I don't think any free app is available for complete office suite functionality. You can try [QuickOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qo.android.am3) or [Documents to Go](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogoapp)

Comment: Wildfire already includes QuickOffice.

Comment: App recommendations are generally off-topic here. Better to ask how to solve a particular problem.

Comment: +1 For Documents To Go which supports the Microsoft Office 2007/2010 formats. It also allows access to Google Docs, you can edit and sync documents back up to Google's servers.

Comment: By "office 2010" do you mean Microsoft Office 2010? Not trying to nit pick but there are other office suites (OpenOffice.org and WordPerfect Office).

Comment: @Space Cracker: A couple people voted to close this question so I edited it to make it more appropriate for this site.  It may seem like we are over stressing semantics but "Is there an app that..." questions can get out of hand, plus in many cases no special app is needed so we've found it better to ask "How do I...".

Comment: @matt: ok, thnx

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to substitute Google Docs for Microsoft Officer there are a number of free options.

If Microsoft Office compatibility is a must there is a free app called [OliveOfficePremium](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.olivephone.edit).  It allows for editing of Word, Excel and Powerpoint documents.  It is free but it has somewhat mixed reviews.

Most of the other Office compatible apps offer a free version that usually only allows you to view docs, and a premium version (usually $10 or more) to edit.

Answer (score 2):

Why not google documents?

You can access google documents from your android phone and create and edit any document you want, and as part of the google documents functionality you can export these documents to multiple formats, including but not limited to Microsoft Office formats.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your device. Its likely that your manufacturer/carrier has packaged your device with one full premium office suite.

If there are none, jump to Play Store. Generally, all vendors publish a office viewer for free which could advertise their premium paid app having editing feature. But still, there are some Office Suites which allow editing for free:

- [Kingsoft Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng)
  Highly Rated & also recommended by me. It'll give you real office editing experience for free.
- [Olive Office Premium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olivephone.edit)