# MS Office Client for Android

Tags: ms-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create and edit Microsoft Office documents in Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/how-can-i-create-and-edit-microsoft-office-documents-in-android)

I just bought a new Galaxy Tab P1000 and I want to open my office documents like Excel, Word, and Powerpoint.

Is there already a client like Microsoft Office for Android?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great app called DocumentsToGo which lets you open MS Office files. If you want to be able to create new ones and edit them in your mobile phone, you need to buy a licence for their app, but otherwise you can use it for free.